# Need to implement OAuth 1.0a in Quarkus for a legacy Twitter API integration. Any suggestions on where to start?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, quarkus, twitter-oauth

For one of our apps, we still use Twitter API v. 1.1., which does not support OAuth2. This means, I won't be able to rely on the OIDC configuration, but develop my authentication mechanism.

Could anyone provide me with some starting points on how to do that? Many thanks!